# "missing separator" in makefile

Tags: makefile, tabs, separator

I don't know a lot about makefiles but get their general purpose. I've installed all of the dependencies for a project and I'm simply trying to run make on an old makefile, however I get the following error:

"makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop"

As I understand it this means that it's looking for a tab/etc., however this is all that is on lines 1-3:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
```

I already had to convert this file from all-spaces to tabs, however I wouldn't think a tab or other separator would be required here. This is from an old project so I'm sure this won't be the first problem I run into but I can't find a formatting tool or anything else online to help.

(edit: if I do put a tab there it turns into an entirely different error so I feel like this is an encoding issue or something?)

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a normal Makefile, it is a perl script. The make command won't work with it.

To execute the script you either need to run

```
perl makefile
```

or give it the execute permission and run it that way with

```
chmod +x makefile 
./makefile
```

Comment: I'm a dummy. I'm a bit inexperienced with Linux but should have figured that out. Thanks.